# Avoid duplicating code for applying tactics in both hypothesis and goal

Tags: coq

I find my self (sort of) duplicating code because I want to the same tactics in the goal and in a hypothesis when they match.  For example:

```
match goal with
| H : PATTERN |- _ => simpl in H; rewrite X in H; ... ; other_tactic in H
| |- PATTERN       => simpl     ; rewrite       ; ... ; other_tactic
end.
```

If the tactics in the match cases becomes long, I essentially duplicate it, with some `in` clauses added, and this seem very unsatisfactory, in particular if I have many match clauses, so that I duplicate a lot of code.

Sometimes it is not because that I am matching, but simply that I have defined a custom tactic, but depending on the context I would like to apply it either to the goal or to a named hypothesis. For example:

```
Ltac my_tac      H := simpl in H; rewrite X in H; ... ; other_tactic in H.
Ltac my_tac_goal   := simpl     ; rewrite X     ; ... ; other_tactic.
```

Then I am again "duplicating" code.

Are there any ways of avoiding this kind of duplication?

At some point I wondered of the goal had a name, say `GOAL`, like hypothesis, so that `simpl in GOAL` was equivalent to `simpl`, but I suspect this is not the case. In that case I  could drop the definition of `my_tac_goal` and then just call `my_tac GOAL` instead.

Any suggestions on how to avoid this kind of duplication would be appreciated.

PS I had a hard time coming up with a good title, so if somebody thinks of one that fits well, do not hesitate to change it.

Answer (score 1):

The "name" of the goal in an `in` clause is `|- *`, but somehow I can't find a reference in the manual for this. E.g. the following works:

```
Goal 2+2=4 -> 2+2=4 -> 2+2=4.
intros H1 H2.
simpl in H1 |- *.
```

This applies simpl in H1 and the goal, but not in H2.

Comment: I see, that seems to work sometimes, however, I cannot get it to work when I define tactics myself :/ Any tips to how this can be done, either with `Ltac` or `Tactic Notation`? I managed to find something about `|- *` in the documentation, namely, under [Occurrence clauses](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html?highlight=simpl#occurrence-clauses).

Comment: I am using this in tactics. Can you post a minimal example where it does not work?

Comment: I have tried something like this: `Ltac foo H := simpl in H.  Lemma bar: forall n : nat, 0 + n = n.  Proof. foo |- *.`, but I get a syntax error at `foo |- *`.

Comment: OK, you can't pass "|- *" as argument to a tactic - that's what I meant with the quotes around "name" above. I don't see an elegant way to solve this in Ltac1. It might be easier in Ltac2, where you have access to the low level machinery without using the notations.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is often a useful pattern, including for Coq developments!

Regarding the particular use case you describe, it seems you could benefit from the [SSReflect tactical `in`](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html#localization)?

Proof-of-concept:

```
Require Import ssreflect.

Section SomeTest.

Variables (T : Type) (a b : T).

Hypothesis L : a = b.

Ltac my_tac := simpl; rewrite L.

Lemma test (c : T) (H : let _t := tt in (* dummy let-in to exemplify [simpl] *)
                        (a, c) = (c, b)) :
  let _t := tt in (b, c) = (c, a).

  do [ my_tac ] in H.
  my_tac.

  exact: H.
Qed.

End SomeTest.
```

Obviously, the `do [ … ] in H` form won't be applicable for any tactic (e.g., an `apply/view.` tactic should be manually ported to some `move/view.` tactic), but nothing prevents you from extending the `my_tac` tactic (e.g., with some if-then-else…), so that relevant parts are adapted manually (or removed) to address both kinds of contexts.